# Can you ping someone in chat who has never been there before?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, ping

I has a discussion [over here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13354880#13354880) over whether if you @ping someone from the main site in chat if they would ever get a notification.

I was under the impression that they would not.

Is this true?

Comment: Mods can do this via super ping. But not mortals like us.

Comment: I was under the impression that talking to people until they themselves speak is rude and can scare them away, and that's why our bot no longer does that.

Comment: I was wrong, apparently only mods can do it.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer (with some sort of source if you can) @Mysticial ?

Comment: Turns out there is a [tag:super-ping] which you can search for to find a little more information.

Comment: @Jhawins You meant [meta-tag:super-ping]?

Comment: @michaelb958 Umm... Yes? That's why I said it. I also posted the tag as well.

Comment: @Jhawins You linked to the main-tag rather than the meta-tag; that's what I was pointing out (if, admittedly, a little obscurely).

Comment: @michaelb958 I'm not doing so hot this week. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Moderators have the power to [super-ping](/questions/tagged/super-ping) any user on any site anywhere in the network.

But mortals like us are left powerless behind a sound-proof glass window to stare at the person we want to reach soooooooo badly.

Comment: Puny mortal. You do not deserve such power.

Comment: @Mysticial You could provide this answer to the question this question is a duplicate of as well or move it there because the information is missing there and will be found from this question from the duplication mark.